# How to replace a commented line in sudoers file with sed via Salt Stack?

Tags: sed, comments, salt-stack, sudoers

Hi I would like to change the following line in the /etc/sudoers file on all of my Salt minions.

```
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

With the following:

```
%wheel          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/salt*
```

So far I have tried the following command along with a plethora of similar commands with slightly different options/syntax:

```
sed -i '/# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL/c %wheel          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/salt*' /etc/sudoers
```

I don't get an error message from this particular command, however file is not updated.

Could anyone provide me with the correct option/syntax for my specific use?

Comment: It would be better to use `file.line` or `file.replace` than to use a `sed` command. Or use `file.managed` in `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed -i 's|# \(.*\)ALL|\1/usr/bin/salt*|' /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ***sed*** expression:

```
sed 's~^# *\(%wheel *ALL=(ALL) *.*\)ALL~\1/usr/bin/salt*~' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @RomanPerekhrest however this updated all entries in my sudoers file with # %wheel

Comment: It also remained commented out

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to run this command against all minions via Salt (using @CWLiu's answer) you must add the following:

```
salt -C 'G@roles:apiserver' cmd.run 'sed -i '"'"'s|# \(.*\)ALL|\1/usr/bin/salt*|'"'"' /etc/sudoers'
```

To comply with Salt Stack's cmd.run syntax